# Chinese names and Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am building an application using MySQL, where Chinese names need to be stored in the database.  I'm trying to decide whether or not using the basic `utf8` encoding (which only works with the Basic Multilingual Plane, and stores a maximum of 3 bytes per character in a UTF-8 encoding), or if I need to make use of the `utf8mb4` encoding, which permits characters from higher planes to be encoded/stored.

Is the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) sufficient to store all Chinese proper names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** it doesn't matter, stick with `utf8mb4` encoding, especially for new applications.

Long-form answer: the key difference between the two encodings is that `utf8`, long supported by MySQL, supports UTF8-encoded characters up to three bytes in length. As of 5.5.3, as noted by @rick-james, a new encoding, `utf8mb4` relaxes this restriction, and otherwise has no disadvantages.

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html), the newer `utf8mb4` encoding lifts this arbitrary three-character restriction, and there are few, if any disadvantages:

> - For a BMP character, `utf8` and `utf8mb4` have identical storage characteristics: same code values, same encoding, same length.
> - For a supplementary character, `utf8` cannot store the character at all, whereas `utf8mb4` requires four bytes to store it. Because `utf8` cannot store the character at all, you have no supplementary characters in `utf8` columns and need not worry about converting characters or losing data when upgrading `utf8` data from older versions of MySQL.

Thus, my original question was misconceived: the maximum number of bytes to encode each character of a Chinese name *shouldn't matter* so long as the encoding you use actually supports encoding all Unicode code points.

Comment: A disadvantage is with the 767-byte limit on indexes (until 5.7).  There are multiple workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8` only handles 3-byte UTF-8 codes (BMP).  Instead, use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, which handles all 4-byte codes.  Yes that includes all of currently defined Unicode for Chinese, Emoji, etc.

Use version 5.7, if practical.

Comment: My original intent in this question was to understand if Chinese names required support for characters outside the Unicode BMP, which is only supported by the three-byte-max `utf8` encoding. As it were, the question itself was slightly misconceived, seeing as for greenfield applications, there seems to be no disadvantages at all with starting with the `utf8mb4` encoding, seeing as character take up the same amount of space anyway.

Comment: Chinese does have some non-BMP characters.